# Javascript/jQuery: Replace items in string matching {x} with "jQuery('#resultsx').val()"

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a string that contains a formula such as

```
{1}+{2}-{3}*{4}
```

Which I would like to turn into the value of different input fields such as

```
<input id="results1" value="15">
<input id="results2" value="25">
<input id="results3" value="35">
<input id="results4" value="45">
```

So that it would turn out like

```
15+25-35*45
```

Which would then calculate to -1535

Hopefully I have explained what I want to do clearly but let me know if I haven't. I have tried using regexps but just can't quite get my head around it and I'm not sure if that's the direction I should be going.

Comment: Well, its easy to match the string `/{(\d+)}/` but what do you do in the replacement?

Comment: "{1}" would go to "#results1" which would go to "jQuery('#results1').val()" which would be "15".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) can take a function as a 2nd parameter.  That will help out here:

```
var equ = '{1}+{2}-{3}*{4}';
equ = equ.replace(/{(\d+)}/g, function(match, $1){
    return $('#results'+$1).val();
});
```

Comment: And at the end you want `eval(equ);`

Comment: @remus: Once you validate that the string only contains numbers and operators :)

Comment: Yes this is what I am looking for! Just so I can understand it properly for next time... what does "function(match, $1)" do? Also what is the best way to strip the {}'s? At the moment it is doing #results{1} instead of #results1.

Comment: @joshhunt: Check the docs for `.replace()` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).  The first parameter (`match`) is the *entire string*, then the next are the match groups (anything inside parenthesis).  There was a bug in my answer, it should be `$('#results'+$1)`.  The regex should take care of the `{}`.